# ERROR in ./~/constants-browserify/constants.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, redux

I had split up my folders in client-side and server-side, but I didn't work from a parent folder, I acted as if they were 2 different folders... Now I want to deploy to Heroku but I need one main folder for that so I figured to change my webpack.config so I can run scripts from my new root folder. I'm getting a last error which I can't figure out to fix, trying these solutions didn't help me either: [First](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/104), [Second](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2119)

This is the error I'm getting:

```
ERROR in ./~/constants-browserify/constants.json
Module parse failed: /Users/Documents/Twitch/testbot/node_modules/constants-browserify/constants.json Unexpected token (2:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "O_RDONLY": 0,
|   "O_WRONLY": 1,
|   "O_RDWR": 2,
 @ ./src/js/reducers/chat.js 1:0-50
 @ ./src/js/script.js
 @ multi main
```

And this is my webpack.config.js:

```
// changed some loader syntax after reading
// https://webpack.js.org/how-to/upgrade-from-webpack-1/

const path = require(`path`);

const webpack = require(`webpack`);
const {UglifyJsPlugin} = webpack.optimize;

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require(`copy-webpack-plugin`);
const ExtractTextWebpackPlugin = require(`extract-text-webpack-plugin`);
const configHtmls = require(`webpack-config-htmls`)();

const extractCSS = new ExtractTextWebpackPlugin(`css/style.css`);

// change for production build on different server path
const publicPath = `/`;

// hard copy assets folder for:
// - srcset images (not loaded through html-loader )
// - json files (through fetch)
// - fonts via WebFontLoader

const copy = new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
  from: `./src/assets`,
  to: `assets`
}], {
  ignore: [ `.DS_Store` ]
});

const config = {

  entry: [
    `./src/css/style.css`,
    `./src/js/script.js`
  ],

  resolve: {
    // import files without extension import ... from './Test'
    extensions: [`.js`, `.jsx`, `.css`]
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, `server`, `public`),
    filename: `js/[name].[hash].js`,
    publicPath
  },

  devtool: `sourcemap`,

  module: {

    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: extractCSS.extract([
          {
            loader: `css`,
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1
            }
          },
          {
            loader: `postcss`
          }
        ])
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: `html`,
        options: {
          attrs: [
            `audio:src`,
            `img:src`,
            `video:src`,
            `source:srcset`
          ] // read src from video, img & audio tag
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jsx?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: `babel`
          },
          {
            loader: `eslint`,
            options: {
              fix: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jpe?g|gif|webp)$/,
        loader: `url`,
        options: {
          limit: 1000, // inline if < 1 kb
          context: `./src`,
          name: `[path][name].[ext]`
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp3|mp4)$/,
        loader: `file`,
        options: {
          context: `./src`,
          name: `[path][name].[ext]`
        }
      }
    ]

  },

  plugins: [
    extractCSS,
    copy
  ]

};

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === `production`){

  //image optimizing
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(svg|png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
    loader: `image-webpack`,
    enforce: `pre`
  });

  config.plugins = [
    ...config.plugins,
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true, // false returns errors.. -p + plugin conflict
      comments: false
    })
  ];

}

config.plugins = [...config.plugins, ...configHtmls.plugins];

module.exports = config;
```

This is the reducer that is mentioned in the error

```
import {CHAT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED} from 'constants';

const chatReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch(action.type){
  case CHAT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
    console.log(state, action);
    return [...state, action.payload];

  default:
    return state;
  }
};

export default chatReducer;
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong to get this error fixed?

Comment: You should paste the error message into the question directly so that other people can find this question more easily if they search for it (it also saves time for people answering the question because there's no need to wait for the image to load).

Comment: I thought I did that by entering the first line of the error in my question? Which part would you also add? I'll edit it right away

Comment: I meant the whole error message that you get in your terminal (you currently have it as an image). It's just considered better to have it in your question, so it's easy to read and can't suffer from link rot if the image is removed.

Comment: Ohh sorry I misinterpreted that, I thought you meant in the title by saying "the question", yeah you're right, I'll do that

Comment: Aside from that, any leads on how to fix this :/? I'd like to get this up and running asap on Heroku (Thanks for pointing that "text > img" out btw)

Comment: [This GitHub thread](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2119) might be at least somewhat helpful - you could try adding the `json-loader` to see if that helps.

Comment: Yeah I found that one too and added it in my question even, but I think it really has to be something trivial... my code worked 100% before I tried changing it to another folder structure, I thought changing my input and output files would be enough. That reminds me, I should also add another file to this post that's imported in my webpack.config.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that link at all. Are you using `json-loader` now and still getting the error, or did you decide not to use it?

Comment: Reading the comments of jeron-diovis I did not. I hoped somebody would just be able to point out the stupid mistake I made in my paths, I assume that's the prob here.

Comment: I updated my webpack.config, I'm now using webpack 2 and it seems to give more readable information about the error. Just fyi that I updated this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imported a file with the path 'constants', this path was interfering with the node_modules' constants-browserify folder.

By changing the constants' file name and path to it I fixed the error.

Comment: do you know if it's possible to setup resolution priority, so my `constants` file will be included instead of `constants-browserify`?

Comment: @LiubomyrMykhalchenko I assume that's just a webpack setting to be changed, no?

Comment: yes, I think so, but I thought maybe you figured out what exactly should be changed. I played with webpack config a little, but ended up renaming `constants.js` to `const.js`.

Comment: I did something similar. I had to remove an import:    "import { defaultCipherList } from 'constants';"